# Keep getting: No such File or directory when I open the Terminal

Tags: terminal

Every time I open the terminal I keep getting this:

```
bash: /usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.33.0/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have tried reloading. No idea why all of a sudden this has come up. Any guesses guys?

Comment: where is the programming question?

Answer (score 15):

You need to update your nvm via homebrew:

> brew upgrade nvm

Comment: funny thing it started happening after i did "brew install vim" to get the latest vim version on a fresh machine

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after I installed another NVM version manually (forgetting that I have had installed an older version via homebrew).
That resulted in a wrong path within configuration in your .bash_profile, .bashrc or any other similar file which gets started each time you run a new terminal window.

According to https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation, look for something like

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
[ -s $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh ] && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
```

This configuration is normally set while installing of NVM. I have had a wrong path in it, die above will work when your NVM resides in `~/.nvm`

Hope that helps you.